# R: ignore cases that are computationally singular

Tags: r

I have a large number of predictors and I am trying to do all sorts of transformations on them while fitting a robust linear model.Some of these combinations yield computationally singular systems. I was wondering how to identify these systems? I tried the following (note that this is deliberately a silly exmaple meant to make it fail):

```
xx <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x = (1:100), z = 2*(1:100))
zz <- try(rlm(y ~ x + z, data = xx))
Error in rlm.default(x, y, weights, method = method, wt.method = wt.method,  : 
  'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'
length(intersect(class(zz), "try-error")) == 1
[1] TRUE
```

However, it does not work. in the sense that the return breaks the loop in which it is run. Any ideas as to how to handle this? Thanks again!

Comment: I'd recommend using `tryCatch` rather than `try` - it's much friendlier to work with.

Comment: But I'm not convinced your code doesn't work. Just because the error prints doesn't mean it stopped the loop (you can use `try` with `silent = TRUE` to keep the error from printing). Using your data, running `for (i in 1:2) {
    if (i == 1) zz <- try(MASS::rlm(y ~ x + z, data = xx));
    print(i)
}` will print both 1 and 2 (both after the error is printed), thus the loop is not broken by the error.

Comment: Maybe you have an error elsewhere in your loop, not wrapped in `try()`?

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure what the error is then. It does work for me also here. I will explore some more and see if I can either find my error or come up with a better example. Thanks again!

Comment: I keep getting the error when it comes down: Error in solve.default(R, rinv) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.23838e-16
I get that it is an error but why would it not keep going after that, since I am using try and asking to go on.

Comment: I have tracked it down. The error is caused because the model is still fit and try.error is not always "try-error" unlike in this example. There is then no summary and that is what crashes the system. Putting try around summary of the model appears to fix my problem. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is a clear case of multicolinearity.

```
>library(usdm)
>a<-as.data.frame(cbind(xx$x,xx$z))
>vif(a)
     Variables VIF
 1        V1   Inf
 2        V2   Inf
```

There are multiple approach to remove multicolinearity from the data. Ridge Regression is a good approach for that.

1.Please refer    [Predictions of ridge regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895372/predictions-of-ridge-regression-in-r)

2.Principal Component analysis. 
Refer 
Johnson & Wichern (2001). ***Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis (6th Edition). Prentice Hall.***

Comment: Thanks! The error is deliberately created in this example to understand what is going on.